# AFNetworkReachabilityManager in Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking

I try to check internet connection but this block never called:

```
   AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock{(status: AFNetworkReachabilityStatus?) in
            println("a")
        }
```

thanks !

Comment: Did you start monitoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AFNetworking` should be monitoring the internet connection to determine if it is changed or not. From `AFNetworking` documentation:

> Instances of "AFNetworkReachabilityManager" must be started
>   with "-startMonitoring" before reachability status can be determined.

So just add following code before `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock`:

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().startMonitoring()
```